# How do I quit a piped less without quitting the source process?

Tags: pipe, less

I started a process that generates files but also has a lot of printed output. 
I started the process and piped it to less.
The process should have completed a long time ago.
I ls the directory where the files are being generated and find that it has not put out a file since shortly I left at the day, but started generating files again shortly after I got back on my PC.

Then a few days later I noticed the same behavior even though I had not locked or left my computer. 
I found that for some reason when after a few minutes less is no longer following the output and when it is in this state, my file generation stops. I can "catch up" if I <kbd>PgDn</kbd> to the bottom or press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> then the file generation resumes for a little while.

This time I am running a much longer process and I don't want to abort it. Is there a way to either resolve this issue with an internal less command or exit less without killing my process?

Comment: press `F` to put `less` in to follow mode?

Comment: That seems to have been what it needed to stay caught up! process completed without any further stalling! Thanks